# Twincat3 C++ module : fatal error C1083: Unable to open including files: ntddk.h No such file or directory

Tags: beckhof

objective : I want to open the window driver program under the C++module of Twincat3

environment:win10 22H2 + WDK(WDK for Windows 10, version 2004) + TC31-FULL-Setup.3.1.4024.55 + TC31-XAR-Setup.3.1.4024.55
(The document of beckhoff shows the old WDK7 environment)

Try:
test 1.Set WDK environment variables
Variable Name：Wntddk.hC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10
(According to the document plan (link1), it has not been resolved)
test 2.copy ntddk.h from WDK directory to my project directory and include
test 3.Project Right Click Properties ->C/C++->General ->Attach Include Directory -> select ntddk.h directory : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km"

link1:
When building a TwinCAT C++ project, this error message indicates that there is a problem with the WinDDK
installation on your engineering computer.
In case this error message is shown, please check the following according to the WinDDK installation manual
[} 19]:
• Check if you have installed WinDDK
• Check the existence of the environment variable "WinDDK7" and its configured value, as described in
the document above. The value must be equal to the path where WinDDK is installed, including the
first sub-folder. After changing this value a reboot is needed

I want to know if the C++module development of Twincat3 can support window driver development?